# What is the meaning of "finish" in these two sentences?

Tags: grammar

"I have finished my homework": this means that my homework is completed, there is no more homework to be done.

"I have finished doing my homework": this means I have ceased doing the homework, but it does not mean the homework has been completed.

Am I right about this?

Answer (score 1):

To me, both suggest that the work has been completed, and so there is no more homework to do that evening.

I suppose the second might be said by very cheeky teenager, trying to get around their parent without actually lying.

> Have you finished your homework?
>
> I've finished *doing* my homework...

If you want to say that you are stopping for now but will return:

> I'm taking a break from doing homework.

> I'm going to stop for now

> I'm going to finish it off tomorrow.

> I've done enough homework for one day.

> I'm giving up.  Mr Snodgrass will just have to get a half-completed essay.

There are endless variations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are strictly correct; but using the word *finished* will set up an implication that the homework is completed.

Using your second example when your homework is not complete, I would class as deliberate misdirection.

Comment: then what would you suggest if I have ceased doing the homework, without it being completed?

Comment: _I've stopped doing my homework_ has an implication that it isn't finished. _I'm taking a break from my homework_ is even more explicit, of course.

Comment: @ Colin Fine I thought that if I say: "I have stopped doing my homework" it sounds like I have stopped doing homework altogether, like I am never going to do homework again.

Comment: @anouk: it might mean that, but it might mean that I have stopped for the time being, and intend to return to it. You can't tell without context.